# How can i run PHP Preg_match against all POST Data?

Tags: php, preg-match, postdata

I have a HTML form where users submit information, depending how many options the user selects in a form there is a different number of POST data sent, some as an array.

The POST data looks like this with VARDUMP:

```
array(8) { ["animal"]=> string(7) "test123" ["name"]=> string(5) "test" ["goat"]=> string(7) "farm" ["animal2"]=> string(8) "animal2" ["option"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["number"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "s" [1]=> string(1) "3" } ["option4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["grass"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

I wish to run my preg_match against all POST data:

```
if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $data)) || (preg_match("/\\s/", $data))
{
    exit("Illegal characters found");
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: In your preg_match, you have two different variables, do you want to test both regexes against each POST value?

Comment: @Nick Yes thats correct, or just an example of one would suffice

Comment: I've updated it to make it clearer

Comment: Why call `preg_match()` twice instead of putting both patterns as alternatives in the regex?

Comment: `preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-\\s]/', $data)`

Comment: @Barmar i coudn't manage to format it correctly without getting an error, but thanks i will use this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to iterate over the entire `$_POST` array, testing each value with your [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) code:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, function ($v) {
    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $v) || preg_match("/\\s/", $v)) {
        exit("Illegal characters found");
    }
});
```